# setVisibility onStateChanged(PlayerStates.PAUSE() - kaltura/AndroidReferenceApp

Tags: java, android, kaltura

Want to change image visibility to VISIBLE upon Playerstates PAUSE & END.  On Playerstates Play i want to change it to INVISIBLE

What i have right now

```
mPlayerStateListener.onStateChanged(new PlayerStates.PAUSE() {

image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewback);
image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        });
```

Am using kalturas AndroidReferenceApp and trying put code here [github.com/kaltura/AndroidReferenceApp/.../Info.java](https://github.com/kaltura/AndroidReferenceApp/blob/780a07e97da9b54e04fdf396d3f2b0ca9cbba298/DemoApplication/src/com/kaltura/activity/Info.java#L216)

This might be helpful [github.com/kaltura/player-sdk-native-android/.../PlayerViewController.java](https://github.com/kaltura/player-sdk-native-android/blob/master/PlayerSDK/src/com/kaltura/playersdk/PlayerViewController.java)

Any ideas?

Comment: So what is going wrong?  Any errors in Logcat?  Are you sure you want INVISIBLE and not GONE?

Comment: Are not getting any errors except on unit, so nothing to go on there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that make it all work like a charm, What i did wrong was not putting the event listeners inside the players JsCallbackReady.

Spent day's on getting this to work and there is no information about this anywhere so i hope it will help others that want to accomplish this functions in native applications using kalturaSDK

```
// Hooking up to the players API
    playerView.registerJsCallbackReady(new KPlayerJsCallbackReadyListener() {
        @Override


        public void jsCallbackReady() {
         // Player is loaded and we tell it to play the video
            playerView.play();





            playerView.addKPlayerEventListener("playerPaused", new KPlayerEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onKPlayerEvent(Object body) {
                    // Player is paused, do something

                }

                @Override
                public String getCallbackName() {

                    return "onPlayerPaused";
                }

            });

            playerView.addKPlayerEventListener("playerPlayed", new KPlayerEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onKPlayerEvent(Object body) {
                    // Player is playing, do something

                }

                @Override
                public String getCallbackName() {

                    return "onPlayerPlayed";
                }
            });



            playerView.addKPlayerEventListener("playerPlayEnd", new KPlayerEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onKPlayerEvent(Object body) {
                   // Player have finished the video, do something

                }

                @Override
                public String getCallbackName() {

                    return "onPlayerPlayEnd";
                }
            });


        }


    });


}
```